# Titanium Appcelerator, disable paste on textfield

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app made in Appcelerator Titanium in which users type in a lot of text.  Our clients are asking us to disable pasting on the various textfields, because the users are supposed to type in new text every time they access these screen, instead of pasting from another place. Is there a way to do this in Appcelerator Titanium? I haven't found anything on their documentation.

Comment: I don't think that is something you can do, but I would probably experiment with the event listener for 'change'.  I'd check to see how fast someone entered the text into the field.  You get X characters in Y milliseconds, I'd assume someone just pasted in text rather than typing it in.

Comment: Yeah, my google searches didn't turn anything up, either. I don't really like the idea of setting a timer on the change event, 'cause I don't want to create a whole bunch of timers, one of each character entered. I'm thinking maybe comparing previous text Length to current text Length.